# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in python kivy app as an executable file

Tags: python, recursion, kivy, exe

I have tried making an app in python - kivy. After compiling the application into an executable file, I get a large chunk of error text. The following is the beginning and end of that error text while trying to run the finalized exe file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1103, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1103, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

...
...
...

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

These are my program's code files' contents:

main.py:

```
import random
import sys
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')

# Designate Our .kv design file
Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):

    def release(self):
        self.ids.my_button.background_color = 5 / 255, 225 / 255, 120 / 255, 1
        self.ids.my_button.color = 1, 1, 1, 1

    def press(self):
        # Create variables for our widget
        # Update the label
        deck = list(range(1, 43))
        random.shuffle(deck)
        # Create list of 6 values, and assign each with a number between 1 and 42
        random_numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        for i in range(0, 6):
            random_numbers[i] = deck.pop()

        # Sort the array from lowest to highest
        random_numbers.sort()
        self.ids.my_button.background_color = 50 / 255, 225 / 255, 120 / 255, 1
        self.ids.my_button.color = 180 / 255, 180 / 255, 180 / 255, 1

        self.ids.name_label.text = f'{random_numbers[0]}    ' \
                                   f'{random_numbers[1]}    ' \
                                   f'{random_numbers[2]}    ' \
                                   f'{random_numbers[3]}    ' \
                                   f'{random_numbers[4]}    ' \
                                   f'{random_numbers[5]}'
class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

main.kv:

```
<MyLayout>
   BoxLayout:
      orientation: "vertical"
      size: root.width, root.height

      Label:
          font_name: "files/cambriab.ttf"
         id: name_label
         text: "If you had 530M dinars, what would you do with it?"
         font_size: 32


      Button:
          id: my_button
         size_hint: .4, .2
         font_size: 32
         font_name: "files/cambriaz.ttf"
         text: "Make me rich!"
         pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
         background_color: 5/255,225/255,120/255,1
         on_press: root.press()
         on_press: hassanGIF.anim_delay = 1/50
         on_press: hassanGIF._coreimage.anim_reset(True)
         on_release: root.release()

         Image:
            id: hassanGIF
            source: 'files/sequence.zip'
            anim_delay : -1
            anim_loop: 1
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y+400
            size: root.width-400, root.height-400
```

Any help with this error would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using different methods of converting the program into an executable file, but it was to no avail.

I have also tried setting the recursion limit to a fixed value, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Looks like a logger misconfiguration.

Comment: There are no issues with the app when I run it inside the editor; only happens when I turn it into an executable file. Shouldn't I be getting an error while running the app inside of PyCharm so that I can debug it? This is my first time converting a program into an exe file so I'm very confused. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. Can you cause the problem to occur with a simpler layout? Can you give exact steps explaining how you created the executable file and how you are running it? Are you certain there isn't **anything else** in the stack trace?

Comment: I tried deleting all visual elements except for the label and it still produces the same error. I think it has something to do with the Kivy dependencies, but I don't know how to make it so that they are all included in the .exe file when I convert it using "Auto py to exe".

Comment: This is a medium sized program. When it tries to log a message, any message, it fails. Simplify it all the way down to HelloWorld, follow the [logger documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/master/api-kivy.logger.html) example, and reproduce the issue in a tiny program. Then you will have a better understanding of the Root Cause and how to fix it.  Post a new SO question with the tiny program if you're still stuck. [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) an answer to this question if you figure things out by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get a recursion error when I assembled the code you posted.  I modified things a little bit to get rid of other errors.  I set up hassanGIF to be transferred to the Python class using

this at the top of the kivy file

```
hassanGIF: hassanGIF
```

and this at the top of the Python class

```
hassanGIF = Image()
```

and finally, I moved the multiple events for on_press into the press() method.

runnable code:

```
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.image import Image

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')

# Designate Our .kv design file
Builder.load_string('''
<MyLayout>
   hassanGIF: hassanGIF
   BoxLayout:
      orientation: "vertical"
      size: root.width, root.height
      Label:
         # font_name: "files/cambriab.ttf"
         id: name_label
         text: "If you had 530M dinars, what would you do with it?"
         font_size: 32
      Button:
         id: my_button
         size_hint: .4, .2
         font_size: 32
         # font_name: "files/cambriaz.ttf"
         text: "Make me rich!"
         pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
         background_color: 5/255,225/255,120/255,1
         on_press: root.press(self)
         # below functions are moved to the press() method
         # on_press: hassanGIF.anim_delay = 1/50
         # on_press: hassanGIF._coreimage.anim_reset(True)
         on_release: root.release(self)
         Image:
            id: hassanGIF
            source: 'files/sequence.zip'
            anim_delay : -1
            anim_loop: 1
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y+400
            size: root.width-400, root.height-400
''')


class MyLayout(Widget):
    hassanGIF = Image()

    def release(self, my_button):
        print(f"Release: {my_button}")
        self.ids.my_button.background_color = 5 / 255, 225 / 255, 120 / 255, 1
        self.ids.my_button.color = 1, 1, 1, 1

    def press(self, my_button):
        print(f"\npress {my_button}")
        # Create variables for our widget
        # Update the label
        deck = list(range(1, 43))
        random.shuffle(deck)
        # Create list of 6 values, and assign each with a number between 1 and 42
        random_numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        for i in range(0, 6):
            random_numbers[i] = deck.pop()

        # Sort the array from lowest to highest
        random_numbers.sort()
        self.ids.my_button.background_color = 50 / 255, 225 / 255, 120 / 255, 1
        self.ids.my_button.color = 180 / 255, 180 / 255, 180 / 255, 1

        self.ids.name_label.text = f'{random_numbers[0]}    ' \
                                   f'{random_numbers[1]}    ' \
                                   f'{random_numbers[2]}    ' \
                                   f'{random_numbers[3]}    ' \
                                   f'{random_numbers[4]}    ' \
                                   f'{random_numbers[5]}'

        self.hassanGIF.anim_delay = 1/50
        print(self.hassanGIF)
        if self.hassanGIF._coreimage:
            self.hassanGIF._coreimage.anim_reset(True)


class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this bug on builds made with pyinstaller 5.7.0, if you're using it too, you should try build you app with pyinstaller 5.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote I've seen this bug on builds made with pyinstaller 5.7.0, if you're using it too, you should try build you app with pyinstaller 5.6.2.

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Please upvote to share support. Adding an answer to merely explain that another person's answer worked clogs the system.

Comment: @ Ben A. If your reputation does not allow this then is the next best option for others to see it works. Thank you.

Comment: @WorkprintStudios. No. If an answer is usefull, just upvote it and do not create a new answer.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34940419)

Comment: You're spamming this comment and causing congestion. Discontinue.